# How to catch a dump transaction in an SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, transactions, backup, trace

Every day, a job is connecting to a 2005 SQL Server and performs a dump transaction with `truncate_only` (or no_log) and breaks my transactions backups sequence.

I checked the Agent and the task scheduler, none of them is hosting such a job.
It occurs every day at 2:38PM, this I know from the server log showing this kind of error :

> **BACKUP LOG WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY or WITH NO_LOG is deprecated. The simple recovery model should be used to automatically truncate the
> transaction log.**

After digging in the profiler I could not see any column showing the IP of the sessions, either, I could continuously pull data from this query :

```
select * from 
    sys.dm_exec_connections A,
    sys.sysprocesses B
where A.session_id = B.spid
```

But I wonder if I can catch the job since the transaction segment is very small.

On an other side, it would be nice if I could hang the backup itself by locking the transaction file, so I would have the time to see which process is stuck trying to dump the transaction.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a VM hosting SQL Server ? Do you use VEAM backup ? It is an ordinary command that uses VEAM by default when using VEAM backups...

Comment: ...have you checked the default server trace?

Answer (score 0):

Configure Auditing or a Trace to track the additional information.

You can then look back over the output logs and see where it came from.